# Android Navigation component retain current Fragment on Activity rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have single Activity MVVM application with navigation component. When I'm navigating everything works just fine. When rotation occur my app was crashing so then I used

```
findNavController().navigate(PermissionsFragmentDirections.Action_permissionsFragment_to_splashFragment())
```

and app crashed. Then I changed to

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.splashFragment)
```

And now this works. Strange but this appear only in `onRequestPermissionsResult`. On other places I'm using it like on first code sample.

I managed to fix that but now when I rotate screen I'm back to start of my `navigation_graph`.

For navigation I have `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` inside my `activity_home.xml`

So my question is how to retain current `Fragment` on `Activity` rotation?

**Added code**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)
    binding.viewModel = settingsViewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    //small constraintlayout for showing state of app online/offline
    constraintLayoutStanje.setOnClickListener {
        settingsViewModel.progress()
        val id: String = getId(this)
        settingsViewModel.settings(id)
    }

    setObservers()

    //all time running task
    Handler().postDelayed({
        mHandlerTask.run()
    }, interval)

}
```

Observers

```
fun setObservers() {
    //status
    settingsViewModel.status.observe(this, Observer {
        when (it) {
            NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEINT -> this.constraintLayoutStanje.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this,
                    R.color.greenStat
                )
            )
            NacinDelaEnum.OFFLINE -> this.constraintLayoutStanje.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this,
                    R.color.redStat
                )
            )
            NacinDelaEnum.ONLINEEXT -> this.constraintLayoutStanje.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    this,
                    R.color.yellowStat
                )
            )
        }
        settingsViewModel.doneProgress()
    })

    //Toast
    settingsViewModel.toastMessage.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
            toast(it)
            settingsViewModel.doneToast()
        }
    })


    //progressBar
    settingsViewModel.pb.observe(this, Observer {
        pb.visible(it)
    })

}
```

NavHostFragment in `activity_home.xml`

```
<fragment
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayoutStanje"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
```

My `nav_graph.xml`

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Navigation component retains the current fragment on rotation so the problem must be with your code. Post your code here.

Comment: Added everything I taught can cause a problem.

Comment: What is the solution?  I have the same issue.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky haven't solved it because we're using only portrait I didn't want to spend too much time solving it. If you find solution post it here also.

Comment: @Michael Hathi Are you sure with that? What is the proof? "Navigation component retains the current fragment on rotation so the problem must be with your code."

Comment: @valerybodak read under 'The Navigation component provides a number of other benefits' over here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation. (Also, I am happily using navigation components in my apps)

Comment: @Michael Hathi. Please clarify where have you found info about fragment's retaining in the official documentation? Please quote here.

Comment: I was referring to >Handling fragment transactions. But, I guess that's not a valid reason to believe it'll survive configuration changes. Kindly point us in the right direction so that it can help us all positively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your manifest file,

```
`<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">`
```

More Information,
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: Not recommended. Your overall app architecture will suffer by using a shortcut like this. You may as well just make apps stuck in portrait if you do this, then you may as well just make iphone apps I suppose.

Comment: Documentation about this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#restrict-activity